# Problema creando llave foránea, migraciones SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

estoy intentando crear dos tablas en mi base de datos, cada columna que quiero utilizar como referencia es de tipo unsignedBigInteger y sigo con el mismo problema

esta es mi migración para `create_location_groups_table`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('location_groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('thumbnail');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('location_groups');
}
```

y esta es la migración para create_location_group_place_table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('location_group_place', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('group_id');
        $table->bigInteger('place_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('type');
        $table->foreignId('group_id')->references('id')->on('location_groups')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('place_id')->references('id')->on('places')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('location_group_place');
}
```

he intentado tanto con  `$table->unsignedBigInteger('group_id');` como con `$table->bigInteger('group_id')->unsigned();` y de ambas maneras el mensaje de error es el mismo

```
  SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'group_id' (SQL: create table `location_group_place` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `group_id` bigint unsigned not null, `place_id` bigint not null, `type` bigint unsigned not null, `group_id` bigint unsigned not null, `place_id` bigint unsigned not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
```

no entiendo cuál puede ser el problema, buscando en internet la solución es utilizar unsigned, pero ya lo estoy haciendo. además el mensaje de la consola es que la columna ya existe en la tabla, y es algo obvio, si yo la estoy creando

Comment: Ya has intentado usar otro nombre para la columna de: ```$table->unsignedBigInteger('group_id');``` en la tabla: ```'location_group_place'``` ?

Comment: fue todo un lío, al final tuve que hacer eso, pero ya está, gracias

Comment: Hola @BetaM el intenta tomar como referencia la columna "group_id" de la tabla: ```location_groups``` , pero en su tabla: ```location_group_place``` el tiene una columna ```group_id```, quizá al momento de cambiarle el nombre a: ```$table->unsignedBigInteger('group_id');``` ese error pueda desaparecer. ¿tu que opinas? ¿En donde crees que pudiera estar el error?

Comment: De la documentación: *"`foreignId` es un alias de `unsignedBigInteger`"*, es decir, que estás creando la misma columna dos veces. Sólo quita el de `unsignedBigInteger`.

Comment: Le entendí mejor a @Sal, no sabía que ```foreignId``` era un atajo para ```unsigedBigInteger```, @André has intentado cambiar esa propiedad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-foreignId):

> El método `foreignId` es un alias del método `unsignedBigInteger`.

De tal manera que estás creando la misma columna dos veces.
Tan sólo quita el de `unsignedBigInteger`:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('location_group_place', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('place_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('type');
        $table->foreignId('group_id')->references('id')->on('location_groups')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('place_id')->references('id')->on('places')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```